# MySQL pivot table - show only records of A where not in list of ids in B

Tags: mysql, sql, select, join, relational-database

I have a users table, a categories table and a user_category table as a pivot. I would like to choose multiple IDs from the categories table then generate a query that displays only records for users who are not in one of the selected categories.

So if a user is a member of two categories and I choose to exclude one of those categories in my 'NOT IN' query, they do not appear in my results.

Here's what I have now:

```
select distinct users.id, users.firstname, users.lastname, users.email from users INNER JOIN user_category ON users.id = user_category.user_id WHERE user_category.category_id NOT IN (280, 210, 177, 207, 240, 157, 187, 246, 153, 208, 199, 156, 281, 211, 212, 220, 218, 170, 201, 222, 236, 233)
```

The problem is, if a user is in category 280 and also one of the categories I did not select, they still show up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT id, firstname, lastname, email 
FROM users
WHERE id not in (
    SELECT user_id
    FROM user_category
    WHERE category_id IN (280, 210, 177, 207, 240, 157, 187, 246, 153, 208, 199, 156, 281, 211, 212, 220, 218, 170, 201, 222, 236, 233)
)
```